# Can block scout connect to a full node and index the transactions in the DB or does it need to be connected to an archive node?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, explorers, explorer-api, blockscout

For my project, I want to query the database that will be created and filled by Blockscout (an open-source block explorer). I have set up a full Ethereum node using Geth and Teku that is currently syncing. Can I connect my blockscout to Geth and have it index all the transactions from the beginning into the PostgreSQL database that it creates so that I can make queries to it? Or does Blockscout have to be connected to an archive node to do that?

Comment: You can just use the full node to run the indexer there. Does not have to be archive node.